# Mapping a specific iteration number to an n-dimensional list/array

Tags: python, mapping

I'm aware that there's `itertools.product` for loops, but I wanted to write something that would return an arbitrary coordinate in n-space given the iteration number that would yield it in a loop. I've already written something that's similar, viz.

```
def clock(iteration_number, axis_lengths):
    dimension=len(axis_lengths)
    coordinate = []
    for i in range(dimension):
        s = axis_lengths[dimension-i-1:dimension-i][0]
        g = iteration_number % s
        iteration_number /= s
        coordinate += [g]
    return tuple(reversed(coordinate))
```

but I'm hoping that, with the help of the built-in function `divmod` (or another) it may be compressed to a list comprehension; I've been trying to use `lambda` functions and `map` as well, but to no avail, so I'm stuck. For example, running the above function on an array `A` with axes lengths `[6, 14, 9, 13, 17]` (i.e. a 5-dimensional array) for iteration number `98000` results in the coordinate `(3, 7, 2, 5, 12)`. How can I do this, i.e. map a specific iteration number to its location in an n-dimensional array? And again, my goal is not to write another function like that above.

Comment: I'am not sure I understand correctly what makes you unhappy with your current solution? Is it speed? Is it code length (you'd prefer to use as many builtin as possible)? Is it that you are creating and storing a gigantic tuple just for the sake of iterating over it and would prefer an iterator that spits values 1 by 1 then forget about them?

Comment: @JulienBernu It's not so much speed, I just feel like a one-liner should exist for this problem, but I cannot think of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the example you give (your code yields a different result from the one you quote). But the built-in one-liner to do the same operation is `np.unravel_index`:

```
import numpy as np
import operator
def product(iterable):
    return reduce(operator.mul, iterable)

def clock_1(iteration_number, axis_lengths):
    dimension=len(axis_lengths)
    coordinate = []
    for i in range(dimension):
        s = axis_lengths[dimension-i-1:dimension-i][0]
        g = iteration_number % s
        iteration_number //= s
        coordinate += [g]
    return tuple(reversed(coordinate))

def clock_2(iteration_number, axis_lengths):
    return np.unravel_index(iteration_number % product(axis_lengths), axis_lengths)

print "clock_1:", clock_1(98000, (6,14,9,3,17))
print "clock_2:", clock_2(98000, (6,14,9,3,17))


clock_1: (3, 3, 4, 1, 12)
clock_2: (3, 3, 4, 1, 12)
```